# Ubuntu 20.04 reverted back to Noveau drivers - why?

Tags: nvidia

I recently installed 20.04 with proprietary Nvidia drivers. Today when I booted, the login screen was in 640x480, and so was the desktop when I logged in, and everything was extremely slow. Turns out the Nvidia driver was now replaced with the Noveau driver. Why and how did this happen, and how can I prevent it from happening again?

Comment: Actually, Until recently it was always `nouveau` that was installed. But since 20.04 You should be given a choice when you install the OS... Were you offline when you completed the installation?

Comment: No no, I chose the Nvidia driver during installation, and it has been running with the Nvidia driver for a month or so without trouble. It was only today it had reverted back to the Noveau driver.

Comment: Ah, what *else* has changed recently on your device? Have you added or made changes to any software or hardware?  Have you made changes to any configs?

Comment: None other than regular updates...

Comment: Reinstall Nvidia drivers.

Comment: *which* updates? Your system will not change spontaneously.  There has to be some cause.  It wasn't a gremlin!  You need to dig deeper into what changes you made to your device.

Comment: I have reinstalled Nvidia driver. I'd love to dig deeper and find out what changes were made and when and why, but how? How do I find out when and how the driver switch was made?

Comment: I have a similar problem where Ubuntu 20.04 reverts to using the Nouveau driver after every reboot despite Nvidia drivers being present on the system. I have to keep reinstalling Nvidia drivers after every reboot as a workaround for this problem :(